# Android 16-Bit Color Image to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rgb, 16-bit

I am trying to get a 16-bit color image that is 80 x 60 resolution from an embedded camera ([datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/451/uCAM-DS-rev7-3555.pdf)). I am successfully able to get 9600 (80 * 60 * 16 / 8) bytes from the camera, but I have a problem displaying the image. I am using the following code to convert the byte array into a Bitmap:

```
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 60, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(jpegBytes));
```

jpegBytes is the array of the image's bytes and it is 9600 bytes long.

Right now, I am getting images that look like this:

[image: corrupted image]

99% of the time. However, I am able to get non-corrupted images that look like this:

[image: uncorrupted image]

very rarely. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? Thanks so much!

UPDATE:

It seems like all the pixels are in the correct spot, but have their RGB values mixed up. For example, the white portion between both photos is the same because the order of RGB does not matter to get white. However, it is clear that the colors are mixed up because the red chair is showing up as blue in the corrupted image and the blue backpack is showing up as green in the corrupted image

Comment: It looks like the image structure is correct but the colors are off. Are you sure that the image is always supposed to be RGB_565 format? Also, are you sure that the image data is raw pixels (and not, say, a jpeg encoding)?

Comment: According to the camera's datasheet, the image is supposed to be transmitted in RGB_565 format. I was able to get 4-bit and 8-bit grayscale images from the camera and display them using ARGB_8888, but the application crashes when I use ARGB_8888 to display the 16-bit image. This is because there are 2 bytes per pixel in a 16-bit image, rather than the 4 bytes per pixel that ARGB_8888 needs.

Comment: Perhaps it is a byte order issue. What happens if you use `bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(jpegBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN));`?

Comment: I tried both Little Endian and Big Endian, but I still get the same screwed up picture.

Comment: It seems like all the pixels are in the correct spot, but have their RGB values mixed up. For example, the white portion between both photos is the same because the order of RGB does not matter to get white. However, it is clear that the colors are mixed up because the red chair is showing up as blue in the corrupted image and the blue backpack is showing up as green in the corrupted image.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Config.ARGB_8888` as bitmap config

From the docs for [public static final Bitmap.Config RGB_565](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) :

> Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes and only the RGB channels are encoded:
>   red is stored with 5 bits of precision (32 possible values), green is
>   stored with 6 bits of precision (64 possible values) and blue is
>   stored with 5 bits of precision. **This configuration can produce slight
>   visual artifacts depending on the configuration of the source.** For
>   instance, without dithering, the result might show a greenish tint. To
>   get better results dithering should be applied. This configuration may
>   be useful when using opaque bitmaps that do not require high color
>   fidelity.

Comment: Unless the data in the buffer is ARGB_8888 format (which OP says it is not), this will not work at all.

Comment: According to the camera's [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/451/uCAM-DS-rev7-3555.pdf) page 8 says that the 16-bit color image is transmitted as a raw 565(RGB) image, so Android's RGB_565 should theoretically work.

Answer (score 0):

I was with a similar problem, and this is how I solve it:

(1) Check the byte array you have received , see if you need to reverse it first before wrap it into ByteBuffer

(2) Check the ByteBuffer endianness, see if you need to change it to little endian (the default byte ordering is big endian)

In my case, I have to reverse the byte array first, change the ByteBuffer to little endian, then I can get a correct image.

Pseudocode:

```
byte[] imageData ;  (byte array received)
reverseByteArray(imageData);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageData);
ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(buffer.capacity());
newBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.capacity(); i++) {
            byte b = buffer.get(i);
            newBuffer.put(b);
        }
newBuffer.flip();
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(newBuffer);
setImage(bitmap);

//------
public static void reverseByteArray(byte[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return;
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = array.length - 1;
        byte tmp;
        while (j > i) {
            tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
            j--;
            i++;
        }
    }
```